# Javascript execute task in worker thread

Tags: javascript

I'm learning asynchronous programming of javascript recently, it seems javascript does not have 'thread-api' like java.
In android, We can put slow functions into worker thread to avoid blocking ui operation.
So, how to implement the java function below via javascript:

```
public void execAsync() {
        new Thread(){
            slowFunction();
        }.start();
}
```

Comment: For the browser https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Answer (score 2):

What you can thread in java in javascript it may be a ***'web worker'***.(i will give you and example with object+arrays not just a simple string)

```
let thread = new Worker("worker.js");
```

They communicate with messages

```
 thread.postMessage([first.value,second.value]);
 console.log('Message posted to worker');
```

at worker.js

```
onmessage = function(e) {
  console.log('Message received from main script');
  var workerResult = 'Result: ' + (e.data[0] * e.data[1]);
  console.log('Posting message back to main script');
  postMessage(workerResult);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript and Java have totally different approaches to asynchrony. While Java has thread based concurrency, were the same code can run across different threads and works on the same memory, JS has task based concurrency with different *agents* that can exchange messages with each other.

**Therefore you cannot just translate a thread based coding style into a task based one.**

```
    Task based concurrency:                       Thread based concurrency:

 - time ->           ---- time -->           - time ->   - time ->   - time ->
 +-------+        +-------+ +-------+      +----------+  +----------+ +-----------+
 | Task  |        | task  | | task  |      | Thread   |  | Thread   | | Thread    |
 +-------+        +-----------------+      +--------------------------------------+
 | Agent |<-Msg ->| Agent           |      | Engine                               |
 | -Code |        | -Code           |      | -Code                                |
 | -Mem  |        | -Mem            |      | -Mem                                 |
 +----------------------------------+      +--------------------------------------+
 | Engine                           |
 +----------------------------------+
```

In most cases, one *agent* is enough in JavaScript, as you can offload most tasks (timers, IO) onto the engine:

```
 setTimeout(function() { // Task 1: Register the timer
  // Task 2: Do stuff when the timer triggers
  console.log("test");
 }, 1000);
```

The only case were you would really need more than one agent, is if you have work that you cannot offload, so in other words: Heavy computations. In those cases you can use multiple *agents* (WorkerThreads / ServiceWorkers in browsers, processes in NodeJS). These agents, unlike Java threads, don't share code and memory (except for [SAB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer)s).

To get another WebWorker running in the browser, you have to start one specifying another file to run:

```
 const worker = new WebWorker("worker.js");
```

Then you can [send/receive messages between the agents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers).

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is indeed single-threaded. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/javascript

You can work with **service workers** to get threads, see more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API